# Web Service Consumption C#

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, http-headers, saml

Hi I have One wsdl file at my local machine. I tried testing it through SoapUI by sending an XML request with Header and SAML token asserted. When i added the WSDL file to my project's web reference, I can see the functions/operation which i want to consume and all its parameter which are to be passed but I cannot find a way to add header and SAML token to it.

Also the URL i have to hit is a HTTPS url so i have to add client Certificates.

All this i have tested over SoapUI and i am getting the response.. Al i want is how to send a request through dotnet code when my WSDL is at local. Since i am working for some Highly secured client i cannot reveal any code. I am posting this question on an assumption that this may be a common problem faced by people.

Please demonstrate your solution with an example.

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for solutions? No offense, but SO is a place where people rather assist than give complete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should consume your service with Wcf.  That will allow you to abstract the transport details away from the client code.  With this method you can have separate configurations between the server and client (production using HTTPS, plus no client configuration required, no HTTPS for local dev machine).  There are tons and tons of great tutorials on WCF here and on the internet at large, so I'm not going to post a big long example here, but Google is your friend.

Comment: Use the federation binding in WCF.

Comment: Trust me I want to implement this over our ASP.Net  App and i want to create a request object which has header embedded similar to what i have in XML. please help, If not an example then an idea how this can be done.